# Ansible collect df output and convert to dictionary from set_fact

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I need a help with my playbook. Im currently capturing filesystem and utilization related details from Restricted Bash VM (Management Console) and would like to create Splunk Event & upload to HTTP Event Collector using URI

Using set_fact I tried to create 2 variables for filesystem and utilization, Im unable to create it as a dictionar or convert into to single event

Could you please help me with workaround.
` Ansible PLAY:

```
name: HMC Filesystems 
    raw: monhmc -r disk -n0 | sed -r 's/ ([^ ]*)$/-\1/' | sed "s/.* //g"  | grep -v Mounted | sed -e "s/^/fs_utilization=/g" -e "s/-/  Filesystem=/g" 
    register: result2
    ignore_errors: yes 

  - name: print fs outputs
    debug: 
      var: "{{ result2.stdout_lines | to_json }}" 
 
  - name: HMC Filesystem related variable Assignment 
    set_fact: 
        hmc_filesytem: "{{ item | regex_search('Filesystem.*') | regex_replace('Filesystem=', '')  }}"
        hmc_filesystem_util: "{{ item | regex_search('fs_utilization.*') | regex_replace('fs_utilization=', '') | regex_replace('%.*', '') | regex_replace('%', '')  }}"
        #hmc_fs_dict: "{{ hmc_fs_dict | default([]) + [{ 'hmc_filesystem': item.hmc_filesystem, 'hmc_fs_util': item.hmc_filesystem_util }] }}"
        #hmc_fs_dict: "{{ hmc_fs_dict + hmc_filesystem_util | to_dict }}"
        #dict_var: "{{ dict_var | default({}) | combine({item.hmc_filesystem: item.hmc_fileystem_util}) }}"
        #dict_var: "{{ dict_var | default([]) + [ {'hmc_fs': hmc_filesystem, 'hmc_utils': hmc_filesystem_util } ] }}"
        #hmc_dict: "{{ hmc_dict|default({}) | combine( {item.ansible_facts.hmc_filesystem: item.ansible_facts.hmc_filesystem_util} ) }}"
    with_items: 
      "{{ result2.stdout_lines }}"

  - name: print var stuff
    debug: var=hmc_filesytem
    debug: var=hmc_fs_dict
```

```
Output from Filesystems task 
---------------------------------
TASK [print fs outputs] ***********************************************************************
ok: [hmc1lab] => {
    "[\"fs_utilization=0%  Filesystem=/dev\", \"fs_utilization=1%  Filesystem=/dev/shm\", \"fs_utilization=3%  Filesystem=/run\", \"fs_utilization=0%  Filesystem=/sys/fs/cgroup\", \"fs_utilization=44%  Filesystem=/\", \"fs_utilization=5%  Filesystem=/extra\", \"fs_utilization=2%  Filesystem=/data\", \"fs_utilization=4%  Filesystem=/home\", \"fs_utilization=1%  Filesystem=/dump\", \"fs_utilization=13%  Filesystem=/var\", \"fs_utilization=18%  Filesystem=/var/hsc/log\", \"fs_utilization=0%  Filesystem=/run/user/601\", \"fs_utilization=1%  Filesystem=/run/user/604\", \"fs_utilization=0%  Filesystem=/run/user/600\"]": [
        "fs_utilization=0%  Filesystem=/dev",
        "fs_utilization=1%  Filesystem=/dev/shm",
        "fs_utilization=3%  Filesystem=/run",
        "fs_utilization=0%  Filesystem=/sys/fs/cgroup",
        "fs_utilization=44%  Filesystem=/",
        "fs_utilization=5%  Filesystem=/extra",
        "fs_utilization=2%  Filesystem=/data",
        "fs_utilization=4%  Filesystem=/home",
        "fs_utilization=1%  Filesystem=/dump",
        "fs_utilization=13%  Filesystem=/var",
        "fs_utilization=18%  Filesystem=/var/hsc/log",
        "fs_utilization=0%  Filesystem=/run/user/601",
        "fs_utilization=1%  Filesystem=/run/user/604",
        "fs_utilization=0%  Filesystem=/run/user/600"
```

`

Would like to create a dictionary from df command with filesystem and their utilisation and feed to Splunk HTTP event collector as a single event using URI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: ***"Create a dictionary from the `df` command with the filesystem and their utilization."***

A: Use the [*community.general.jc*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_conversions.html#converting-to-json) filter. Declare the variable

```yaml
  df: "{{ df_out.stdout|community.general.jc('df') }}"
```

and get the data

```yaml
    - command: df
      register: df_out
```

---

The implementation of the *df* utility and the data format differs among the systems. For example, Linux reports `Use%`, e.g.

```bash
shell> df /
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p6  40054040 29539152   8450504  78% /
```

As a result, you get

```yaml
  df:
  - 1k_blocks: 40054040
    available: 8452212
    filesystem: /dev/nvme0n1p6
    mounted_on: /
    use_percent: 78
    used: 29537444
```

but *BSD systems reports `Capacity`, e.g.

```bash
shell> df /
Filesystem          512-blocks    Used     Avail Capacity  Mounted on
zroot/jails/test_11  202537888 1114560 201423328     1%    /
```

As a result, you get

```yaml
  df:
  - 512_blocks: 202537888
    available: 201423328
    capacity_percent: 1
    filesystem: zroot/jails/test_11
    mounted_on: /
    used: 1114560
```

---

Use the filter [*ansible.utils.replace_keys*](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.utils/blob/main/docs/ansible.utils.replace_keys_filter.rst#ansibleutilsreplace_keys) and rename the `capacity_percent` key to `use_percent`

```yaml
    df_used: "{{ df|ansible.utils.replace_keys(target=_target) }}"
    _target:
      - before: capacity_percent
        after: use_percent
```

and create the dictionary

```yaml
    mount_percent: "{{ df_used|items2dict(key_name='mounted_on',
                                          value_name='use_percent') }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: test_11,test_13,localhost

  vars:

    df: "{{ df_out.stdout|community.general.jc('df') }}"
    df_used: "{{ df|ansible.utils.replace_keys(target=_target) }}"
    _target:
      - before: capacity_percent
        after: use_percent
    mount_percent: "{{ df_used|items2dict(key_name='mounted_on',
                                          value_name='use_percent') }}"
    
  tasks:

    - command: df
      register: df_out
    - debug:
        var: df

    - debug:
        var: df_used

    - debug:
        var: mount_percent
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [test_11,test_13,localhost] ************************************************************

TASK [command] ******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]
changed: [test_11]
changed: [test_13]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [test_13] => 
  df:
  - 512_blocks: 201990424
    available: 201424472
    capacity_percent: 0
    filesystem: zroot/jails/test_13
    mounted_on: /
    used: 565952
ok: [test_11] => 
  df:
  - 512_blocks: 202538384
    available: 201424472
    capacity_percent: 1
    filesystem: zroot/jails/test_11
    mounted_on: /
    used: 1113912
ok: [localhost] => 
  df:
  - 1k_blocks: 3974864
    available: 3974864
    filesystem: udev
    mounted_on: /dev
    use_percent: 0
    used: 0
  - 1k_blocks: 801304
    available: 798812
    filesystem: tmpfs
    mounted_on: /run
    use_percent: 1
    used: 2492
  - 1k_blocks: 40054040
    available: 8450272
    filesystem: /dev/nvme0n1p6
    mounted_on: /
    use_percent: 78
    used: 29539384
  - 1k_blocks: 4006520
    available: 3627692
    filesystem: tmpfs
    mounted_on: /dev/shm
    use_percent: 10
    used: 378828
  - 1k_blocks: 5120
    available: 5116
    filesystem: tmpfs
    mounted_on: /run/lock
    use_percent: 1
    used: 4
  - 1k_blocks: 4006520
    available: 4006520
    filesystem: tmpfs
    mounted_on: /sys/fs/cgroup
    use_percent: 0
    used: 0
  - 1k_blocks: 107323996
    available: 15491352
    filesystem: /dev/nvme0n1p7
    mounted_on: /export
    use_percent: 85
    used: 86337860
  - 1k_blocks: 98304
    available: 29569
    filesystem: /dev/nvme0n1p2
    mounted_on: /boot/efi
    use_percent: 70
    used: 68735
  - 1k_blocks: 801304
    available: 801288
    filesystem: tmpfs
    mounted_on: /run/user/1000
    use_percent: 1
    used: 16

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [test_13] => 
  df_used:
  - 512_blocks: 201990424
    available: 201424472
    filesystem: zroot/jails/test_13
    mounted_on: /
    use_percent: 0
    used: 565952
ok: [test_11] => 
  df_used:
  - 512_blocks: 202538384
    available: 201424472
    filesystem: zroot/jails/test_11
    mounted_on: /
    use_percent: 1
    used: 1113912
ok: [localhost] => 
  df_used:
  - 1k_blocks: 3974864
    available: 3974864
    filesystem: udev
    mounted_on: /dev
    use_percent: 0
    used: 0
  - 1k_blocks: 801304
    available: 798812
    filesystem: tmpfs
    mounted_on: /run
    use_percent: 1
    used: 2492
  - 1k_blocks: 40054040
    available: 8450272
    filesystem: /dev/nvme0n1p6
    mounted_on: /
    use_percent: 78
    used: 29539384
  - 1k_blocks: 4006520
    available: 3627692
    filesystem: tmpfs
    mounted_on: /dev/shm
    use_percent: 10
    used: 378828
  - 1k_blocks: 5120
    available: 5116
    filesystem: tmpfs
    mounted_on: /run/lock
    use_percent: 1
    used: 4
  - 1k_blocks: 4006520
    available: 4006520
    filesystem: tmpfs
    mounted_on: /sys/fs/cgroup
    use_percent: 0
    used: 0
  - 1k_blocks: 107323996
    available: 15491352
    filesystem: /dev/nvme0n1p7
    mounted_on: /export
    use_percent: 85
    used: 86337860
  - 1k_blocks: 98304
    available: 29569
    filesystem: /dev/nvme0n1p2
    mounted_on: /boot/efi
    use_percent: 70
    used: 68735
  - 1k_blocks: 801304
    available: 801288
    filesystem: tmpfs
    mounted_on: /run/user/1000
    use_percent: 1
    used: 16

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  mount_percent:
    /: 1
ok: [test_13] => 
  mount_percent:
    /: 0
ok: [localhost] => 
  mount_percent:
    /: 78
    /boot/efi: 70
    /dev: 0
    /dev/shm: 10
    /export: 85
    /run: 1
    /run/lock: 1
    /run/user/1000: 1
    /sys/fs/cgroup: 0

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_11: ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, Thank you for very detailed information. The restricted bash VM doesn't have df command itself.  It is customised Linux Console the alternative DF command is "monhmc -r disk -n0"

Comment: Output looks like below 
Filesystem                    1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                       15781376       0  15781376   0% /dev

Comment: Your solution worked. Many many thanks for quick help and fix.